# XAML WPF Polygon (triangle) with border on 2/3 sides only

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a drawn polygon in WPF/XAML like this:

```
    <Polygon
     HorizontalAlignment="Right"
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0"
     Width="20"
     Height="50"
     Points="0 2,0,0 2,1"
     Fill="Transparent"
     Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FFFFFF" StrokeThickness="1" />
```

This puts a white border on all three sides of the triangle. However, I only want a white border on two of the sides (not the left, flat side). On the third side, I want no border at all (this would look like an open triangle... kind of like a greater than sign >). Is there a way to do this? I have played around with the stroke thickness with no luck (doesn't let you specify per side).

Comment: Do you really need the triangular transparent fill, e.g. for hit testing? Then the accepted answer is not what you need. If you don't need the fill, then why not use a Polyline instead of a Polygon, with just two points.

Comment: I needed it to be transparent, it's for a UI design a customer was looking for

Comment: Anyway, the code in the answer does not create a filled triangular shape.

Comment: I wasn't looking for a filled shape, just something that looked like a greater than sign in a way. A triangle with one side missing. I used the path code they provided it and tweaked it for my needs and it looks exactly as I needed.

Comment: Better use a PathGeometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use a Path rather than a polygon. Something like:

```
<Path Stroke="White">
    <Path.Data>
        <GeometryGroup>
            <LineGeometry StartPoint="10,10" EndPoint="30,35"></LineGeometry>
            <LineGeometry StartPoint="30,35" EndPoint="10,55"></LineGeometry>
        </GeometryGroup>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

You may have to tweak the endpoints a bit, but it should get you fairly close to what you're after.

Comment: This is spot on. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In order to create a filled shape with partially stroked edges, use a PathGeometry like this:

```
<Path StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="White" Fill="Transparent">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
                <PolyLineSegment Points="10,10 0,20"/>
                <LineSegment Point="0,0" IsStroked="False"/>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```